# Export graph data into csv in kibana 7.8.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, export-to-csv

I am downloading my graph data only through the inspect option which is by default in *kibana*.
Is there any way that I can add a **DOWNLOAD** button or custom link to generate **CSV**.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which version of Kibana do you use?

Comment: it's 7.8.1 version